# How to set Ubuntu Server to ipv4 network address

Tags: server

I am setting up Ubunut Server version 14 (32 bit) in an Oracle Virtual Box. Install went well and the network is set to Bridged so that the VM uses the host (Win1064bit) network card.

Once logged into Ubuntu the ifconfig gives me a ipv6 address starting with fe80::

The rest of my home network runs on ipv4. and my router (Fritzbox) shows the Ubuntu has been assigned an ipv4 address. When I try the address in the browser on my localhost it times out. I am unsure what to do.

a) is it preferable to force Ubuntu to use an ipv4? if so how? b) is there a way for me to reference the ipv6 via Chrome/browser?

What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

If it were my machine, I would edit the /etc/network/interfaces file.  Here's an example of what the eth0 entry should look like:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.50
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Somewhere towards the top of the file, there should be a line that says

```
auto eth0
```

Or something like

```
auto lo eth0 (basically, "auto blahblahblahblah eth0")
```

This will automatically bring up `eth0` with the IP you specify under `address`.  Make sure you choose the right `netmask` (sometimes referred to as subnet mask) and `gateway` (usually the IP address of your router).

If you do all this, you should have a fully functional IPv4 connection.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thank you for writing.  my ubuntu does not recognise iface or auto.